# Unable to Check a CheckBox in TreeListView (ObjectListView)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, objectlistview

I can't check or uncheck checkboxes in my [TreeListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) for some reason.

Well, I didn't set AspectName because my top level class didn't contain a corresponding property but I used a delegate instead

```
treeElementsColSpoofing.AspectGetter = delegate(object o)
{
    if (o is ClassA)
    {
        return ((ClassA)o).SomeList.Exists(x => x.SomeObject.Name == "Some name");
    }
    return string.Empty;
};
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the OnCheck() event - maybe something's blocking the check/uncheck?

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation around CheckBoxes; http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-use-checkboxes-in-my-objectlistview

In your case you might need to attach a `CheckStateGetter` and `CheckStatePutter` delegate to the view.